# Any way to host OpenRasta code on OWIN/Katana?

Tags: .net, self-hosting, openrasta

What are hosting options for OpenRasta? I really like what I see and read about the framework and ready to give it a shot, but being able to host WITHOUT IIS is a must for my project.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully deployed windows services with the httplistener.

You can find my sample (beware: vb.net) on bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/starlogicsh/openrasta-vbsample/src/d753f2d00177d8af0e10dabef47448bf1ce7ebb9/openrasta%20vbsample/Module1.vb?at=default